# Resharper Method is never used

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-10.0

I have a public facing interface in one project that will end up becoming a nuget package. Here is the code:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    void MyMethod();
}
```

Now every method in this interface is not used in this library but is used in other via the package. However, every single method here has a warning of `Method x is never used.`

Is there a simple way to tell ReSharper to ignore every public method in every project in every solution that I ever open to not perform this check in public methods.

I have a couple of ways to fix this but it is far too tedious.

Option 1: `[UsedImplicitly]` on every method inside my class. This is far too tedious in my opinion.
Option 2: `[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "UnusedMember.Global")]` A little less tedious, but still have to implement on every class.

There has to be a better way?

I also read somewhere that this only happens if `Enable solution-wide analysis` is checked. In my case it is not. I found this setting under `Reshaper Options > Code Inspection > Settings`

Comment: Add a test project and, you know, test the methods!

Comment: `[PublicAPI]` will mark the whole type as implicitly used. I think it should be preferred over `[UsedImplicitly]`. This is rather for reflection usages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, since you've mentioned that SWEA is disabled, I would recommend disabling the following checkbox `ReSharper | Options | Code Inspection | Settings | General | Show unused non-private type members when solution-wide analysis is off`.

Comment: That option does not exist for me. Has it been moved?

Comment: This option was added to ReSharper 2018.1 version. What version do you use?

Comment: On latest, interestingly enough the option is now there. I wonder how I missed it before. I was really careful. In any case this did resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from @Matthias's comment on the original question, for deliberately public methods that are intended for export from your library, use the `[PublicAPI]` attribute on the class from the `JetBrains.Annotations` package and namespace:

```cs
using JetBrains.Annotations;

[PublicAPI]
public interface MyInterface
{
    void MyMethod();
}
```

This is not an ideal answer to the original question as it is just as tedious as applying `[UsedImplicitly]` onto every class. However, for me it has the advantage over a blanket disabling of the inspection as it will point out places where I have made an error in making a method or class public.

It also has an advantage over `[UsedImplicitly]` as it is a positive declaration of the intent that this class is to supposed to used by consumers of the library. `[UsedImplicitly]`, in contrast, would indicate to me that the method/class was used somehow (e.g. de/serialization) with the context of the current solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution #1

You could use

```
 // ReSharper disable UnusedMember.Global
```

If you put this before the method you disable the warning for that method...

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    // ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Global
    void MyMethod();
}
```

If you put it before the namespace declaration you disable the warning for the entire file.

Otherwise you can do like this, so you disable the warning for the interface:

```
[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "UnusedMember.Global")]
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void MyMethod();
}
```

### Solution #2

The last solution you can take is to disable this kind of message in the Resharper Options unchecking Code Inspection -> Compiler Warnings -> Field is never used.

I guess is the only solution that solve your problem withoud passing through all the classes.